# Video does not play on android mobile phone after being recorded using cordova + ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, video, ionic-framework, playback

So here's the case, I am using cordova with ionic to make an app. One of the features of the app is to let the user record their video. This video is then supposed to show up on the app, immediately after being recorded. I have managed to get the app to record the video, which then gets stored in the users's phone. However, when I try to add the video back it doesn't play.

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here's the HTML code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Practise</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/practise.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="videoArea"></div>
        <button id="takeVideo" class="button button-positive button-block">Take Video</button>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/practise.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the JavaScript code to go along with it:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", captureVideo, false);
function captureVideo() {

document.querySelector("#takeVideo").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
        console.log("Take video");
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
    }, false);

}

function captureError(e) {
    console.log("capture error: "+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function captureSuccess(s) {
    console.log("Success");
    console.dir(s[0]);

    var path;

    path = s[0].fullPath;
    document.querySelector("#videoArea").innerHTML = "<video> <source src=\""+path+"\""+" type=\"video/mp4\"> </video>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the device model, cordova version, and ionic version that you are having this issue in.
Also, can you print the fullPath and provide it here.

We might be able to tell you what is going wrong with that information.

You can also look into [Onymos Media component](https://www.onymos.com/products/media), if you would rather use a commercial plugin to get your app to market faster.